# c++ 2d arrays and pointers to pointers- I don't understand this code

Tags: c++

I don't understand pointers to pointers or pointers to 2d arrays. I do not understand what the following code does. Can anyone go line by line and explain to me what it is doing? It is really important for me to grasp this concept, but I cannot grasp it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //i understand that we declare a 2d array
    int tD[2][2];
    //but then i'm confused why there is a pointer to a pointer when there isn't a pointer in the first place
    int **tD2;
    //and i am confused what the star after int does
    tD2 = new int*[2];

    //i think i get this
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        tD2[i] = new int[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        delete [] tD2[i];

    //lost here
    delete [] tD2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An `int **` is not a two-dimensional array.  It is what it says it is -- a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what is the first pointer then? if it is a second level pointer, musn't there be a first level pointer as well?

Comment: The first pointer is a pointer.  All it does is point somewhere.  It could have pointed to a single `int`.  The issue with things like this is that you can be easily fooled into thinking that an `int**` is a two dimensional array when it isn't.  If one were compatible with the other, then [things like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6966885478d32778) would compile without error, and as you can see, there is an error.  And no, don't cast to try and overrule the compiler -- you will get disastrous results.

Comment: Also, a pointer to a two dimensional array in your case is actually `int (*)[2];`, not `int **`.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/624b2ddac44c69eb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave comments to explain...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //i understand that we declare a 2d array
    int tD[2][2];

    //but then i'm confused why there is a pointer to a pointer when there isn't a pointer in the first place
    int **tD2; // A 1D array is an int*; int** makes an array of int*'s, which are themselves arrays (not necessarily all next to each other).

    //and i am confused what the star after int does
    tD2 = new int*[2]; // allocates memory for two int*'s.
    /*
        int* a = new int[2];
        int** b = new int*[2];
        int*** c = new int**[2];

        See the pattern? It's one less * than the type.
    */

    //i think i get this
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        tD2[i] = new int[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        delete [] tD2[i]; // deallocates each inner array.

    //lost here
    delete [] tD2; // deallocate the outer array. (i.e., the array that holds the "inner arrays").

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so if it were a 3d array would you put 3 stars?

Comment: @stoicbutterfly Yep. I was just about to add that! Anything else? Otherwise mark as answer.

Comment: @stoicbutterfly precisely. `int*` is the syntax for that.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I'll mark it as an answer as soon as you get to my second question, no problem! It's making me wait 4 minutes to accept it as an answer, but I will do so in four minutes. And as for the second question, you already answered it, so you're good!

Comment: @stoicbutterfly what second question? I answered it.

Comment: @Charles Your comments are wrong.  An `int**` is not a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How would you explain it then?

Comment: It is what it is -- a pointer to a pointer to `int`.  It is not a 2 dimensional array.  Things like this makes new programmers do things like applying ill-advised casts to an `int**` because they were told it really is a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `int**`'s value is the address of contiguous memory. Is that not an array, conceptually?

Comment: It isn't an array.  If it were, then things like this `int x[2][2]; int **px = x;` would not produce a compiler error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie _conceptually_. That's all I'm trying to say.

Comment: @Charles The memory need not be contiguous.  Even your own answer shows the memory allocated isn't contiguous.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie each level is... my point is that all of the addresses can be found next to each other at each level. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: That's what is different.  An actual 2 dimensional array has its memory layout as contiguous.  Your example does not mimic this that all.  You are calling `new[]` for each row, meaning all of those pointers being returned by `new[]` could be who-knows-where.

Comment: Yes. So what? That's the whole point of heap allocation. It's still conceptually an array at each level. Maybe not a _2D array_, then...?

Comment: My point is that it is not the same -- even the compiler shouts an error at you if you tried to make them the same using assignment, but that doesn't stop the naive programmer from trying to cast an `int**`, and then post on SO asking why their program crashes.  If you want anything close to a real 2D array implemented with an `int**`, then [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e3ddd04caa9c990) comes closer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie understood. Thank you for pointing that out to me... I've edited my comments language a bit. Let me know if it is better...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //i understand that we declare a 2d array
    int tD[2][2];
    //but then i'm confused why there is a pointer to a pointer when there isn't a pointer in the first place
    int **tD2;
```

This defines `tD2` as a pointer (the first `*`) to a pointer ( the second `*`) to an `int`. This isn't useful for anything yet because it is just a pointer and hasn't been pointed at anything. Until it points at something it is dangerous.

```
    //and i am confused what the star after int does
    tD2 = new int*[2];
```

This dynamically allocates an array of two pointers (the `*`) to `int`s and assigns this array to `tD2`. `tD2` now points at something and is safe to use. However the array of pointers is uninitialized and dangerous.

```
    //i think i get this
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        tD2[i] = new int[2];
```

This loop dynamically allocates an array of two `int`s for each of the pointers in the array of pointers to `int`s allocated above to point at. Now all of the pointers are pointing at something.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        delete [] tD2[i];
```

Any memory you dynamically allocate should be returned to from which it came when you are done with it so the memory can be reused or eventually your program  will run out of memory. `delete []` returns an array and makes sure the appropriate destructors are called. This loop releases the arrays of `int`.

```
    //lost here
    delete [] tD2;
```

Releases the array of pointers to `int`s for the same reasons as above.

```
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This is a horrible way to manage a 2D array. Look at all the work you had to do. Think of how easy it is to forget or be unable to return the memory that was allocated. The programmer has to remember the dimensions or pass them around with `tD2` to make sure no one steps out of bounds.

Don't do this. [Instead use `std::vector`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //i understand that we declare a 2d array
    int tD[2][2];
    vector<vector<int>> tD2(2,          // outer vector contains 2 vectors
                            vector(2)); // inner vector contains 2 ints

    return 0;
}
```

`vector` looks after the memory for you. It knows how big all of the dimensions are so it's harder to get lost. It has a method, `at`, that won't let you go out of bounds. It gets bigger if you need it to get bigger. Take that dynamic array! Best of all, it has libraries full of support functions for searching, sorting and manipulating. You have to be a fool not to use `vector`.

Don't be a fool.

If your instructor forces you to be a fool, call them a fool under your breath and pretend you are a fool until you've safely passed the class.

Comment: thanks. yes, my professor is forcing me to do it this way. it is nice to learn better ways to do things. i will keep that in mind for after this class ends. are pointers even used all that often in the programming world?

Comment: @stoicbutterfly Yes. Pointers are used frequently. There is a hierarchy of sorts, though. Prefer no pointer, followed by [references](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/reference) and finally pointers. References are more [restrictive and have less room for error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). That means they can't do some things and you will have to fall back on pointers. The real sin with pointers is knowing if what they point at (and this happens with references as well, but less often) is valid.

Comment: What you really want to avoid isn't so much the pointer, but unmanaged object lifespans. You want to know if you have any type of reference, that nothing has released the storage being referred to. References only go one way. There is no practical way to have a back channel that informs the reference that it's no longer pointing at anything usable. Read up on scope and Smart pointers for help making sure objects are still around when you want them and not lost, cast adrift in memory and never to be freed.